# Using ESI-tags inside a cached object in Varnish

Tags: varnish, esi

I have been following the guide here: https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/tutorial/esi.html

I have two pages in my project as of now:

1. `http://127.0.0.1:3001/` (Cache-Control:max-age=60, private):

   `<b>Cached:</b> <%= Time.now %> <br/>`

   `<b>ESI:</b> <esi:include src="/staticview" /> <br/>`
2. `http://127.0.0.1:3001/staticview` (Cache-Control:max-age=1, private):

   `<%= Time.now %>`

However, every time I request the first page, it seems like it also
caches the ESI-include result for the 60 seconds instead of refreshing
every second.

**First request:**

```
Cached: 2012-07-09 01:31:12 +0200
ESI: 2012-07-09 01:31:12 +0200
```

**Second request (10 seconds later):**

```
Cached: 2012-07-09 01:31:12 +0200
ESI: 2012-07-09 01:31:12 +0200
```

**Third request (about a minute later):**

```
Cached: 2012-07-09 01:32:19 +0200
ESI: 2012-07-09 01:32:19 +0200
```

Is this expected behavior? Or am I misunderstanding the documentation?

My VCL config looks like this:

```
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "3000";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    # Don't cache POST, PUT, or DELETE requests
    if (req.request == "POST" || req.request == "PUT" || req.request == "DELETE") {
        return(pass);
    }

    return(lookup);
}

sub vcl_fetch {
    # We want ESI
    set beresp.do_esi = true;

    if (beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "max-age") {
        unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
        return(deliver);
    }

    # Do not deliver into cache otherwise.
    return(hit_for_pass);
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    if (obj.hits > 0) {
        set resp.http.X-Varnish-Cache = "HIT (" +obj.hits+ ")";
    } else {
        set resp.http.X-Varnish-Cache = "MISS";
    }
}
```

Varnish is running with these parameters:

```
varnishd -F -a 127.0.0.1:3001 -f config/varnish/development.vcl
```

My Varnish version is this (running on Mac OS X, with Varnish from the
Homebrew repo):

```
varnishd (varnish-3.0.2 revision 55e70a4)
Copyright (c) 2006 Verdens Gang AS
Copyright (c) 2006-2011 Varnish Software AS
```